# Db2 human readable error formatter

Tags: database, exception, db2

Almost all clients for DB2 return errors in format

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=103, COLNO=0, DRIVER=3.57.82
SQLState:  23502
ErrorCode: -407
```

Than I should google for SQLCODE, than for SQLState and then try to understand meaning of SQLERRMC. It is time consuming... I would like to know is there tool which parse such format and return human friendly formatted error, such as "You are tring to insert null in position 2 where only non null values posible..."

Answer (score 5):

To convert 'SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=x, TABLEID=y, COLNO=z' to schema, table and column names, at a SQL prompt:

```
SELECT C.TABSCHEMA, C.TABNAME, C.COLNAME
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES AS T,
SYSCAT.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE T.TBSPACEID = x
AND T.TABLEID = y
AND C.COLNO = z
AND C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA
AND C.TABNAME = T.TABNAME
```

Credit: I found this at http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1655517-how-find-table-tbspaceid-2-tableid-1583-a.html

Answer (score 2):

The DB2 version 9 message reference is over [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/c0mintro.htm). Although the messages are pretty consistent from version to version you may want to find the message reference for your specific version.

In your case, SQL 407 is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0407.htm).

Additionally, as the message reference [states](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/c0mintro.htm), if you want to automatically translate DB2 error messages, you can do the following:

> To invoke message help, open the command line processor and enter:
>
> ? XXXnnnnn
>
> where XXX represents a valid message prefix and nnnnn represents a valid message number.
>
> The message text associated with a given SQLSTATE value can be retrieved by issuing:
>
> ? nnnnn
>
> or
>
> ? nn
>
> where nnnnn is a five digit SQLSTATE (alphanumeric) and nn is the two digit SQLSTATE class >code (first two digits of the SQLSTATE value).

In your case above you could enter ?SQL0407 at the CLP prompt and you should get a description of the error message.

Comment: From the Command window or shell, you could do the same by typing: "db2 ? SQL0407" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check for IBM utility `QW` which may help you to get the description and possible resolutions handy.